# List search result in Listbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, search, listbox, telerik

For the new admin. function of my application, there is a `GridView` to show records in database.

There is a `TextBox` to let user input staff name and then click "search" button. I want to show the search result in `ListBox` (show similar staff name). When user click on the name, it will automatically insert into db and then refresh the `GridView`.

How can I databind the `ListBox` based on the `TextBox`? And how can I insert the value when user click `ListBox`? Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ITAlert.aspx.vb" Inherits="DepartmentManager_ITAlert" %>     
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </telerik:RadScriptManager>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                 Text="Staffs to get the email alert:" 
                 Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
      <br /><br />  
      <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                       allowpaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       DataSourceID="LDS" GridLines="None"  pagesize="20"
                       AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" 
                       Style="border: 0; outline: none;"
                       OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand">
        <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" 
                        ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
          <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView DataSourceID="LDS" DataKeyNames="ID">
          <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf">
          </CommandItemSettings>
          <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
          </RowIndicatorColumn>
          <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
          </ExpandCollapseColumn>
          <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DisplayName"
                                     FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column"
                                     HeaderText="Staff Name" ReadOnly="True"
                                     SortExpression="DisplayName"
                                     UniqueName="DisplayName">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this record?"
                                      ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                      ConfirmTitle="Delete" 
                                      ButtonType="ImageButton" Text="Delete"
                                      CommandName="Delete" />
          </Columns>
          <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
            </EditColumn>
          </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
        </FilterMenu>
        <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default">
        </HeaderContextMenu>
      </telerik:RadGrid>
      <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS" runat="server" 
                          ContextTypeName="DataContext"
                          OrderBy="DisplayName" Select="new (ID, DisplayName)"
                          TableName="v_EmailAlerts" Where="Type == 4">
        <WhereParameters>
          <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CID" QueryStringField="CID"
                                    Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>       
      </asp:LinqDataSource>
      <br />
      <br />
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_staffname">
      </asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"
                  OnClick="btnSearch_click"/>
      <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="RadListBox_staff" Height="300px"
                          Width="230px" AllowTransfer="false" 
                          AutoPostBack="false" 
                          style="top: 0px; left: 0px" 
                          DataSourceID="LDS_staff"
                          DataTextField="displayname" DataValueField="sid" >
      </telerik:RadListBox>
      <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS_staff" runat="server"
                          ContextTypeName="dcHRISDataContext"
                          OrderBy="DisplayName" Select="new (SID, DisplayName)"
                          TableName="vHRIS_StaffDBs"
                          Where="Lefe == False and SID is nothing">   
      </asp:LinqDataSource>                
   </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind (with proposed listbox databind function) :

```
Imports Telerik.Web.UI

Partial Class DepartmentManager_ITAlert
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As GridCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.DeleteCommand

        Dim AlertID = DirectCast((DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)).GetDataKeyValue("ID"), Integer)

        'retrive entity form the Db
        Dim dc As New DataContext
        Dim rec = (From a In dc.EmailAlerts Where a.id = AlertID).firstordefault

        If rec IsNot Nothing Then
            dc.HRIS_EmailAlerts.DeleteOnSubmit(rec)
            dc.SubmitChanges()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSearch_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

        Dim sname As String = ""
        sname = tb_staffname.text

        If sname <> "" Then
            Dim dc As New dcHRISDataContext
            Dim rec = (From a In dc.vHRIS_StaffDBs Where a.Lefe = False _
                       And (x >= x.DisplayName.Matches(sname)) Select a.SID, _
                       a.DisplayName Order By DisplayName).ToList

            RadListBox_staff.DataTextField = "DisplayName"
            RadListBox_staff.DataValueField = "SID"
            RadListBox_staff.DataSource = dt
            RadListBox_staff.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

moreover, it display error for the LINQ of searching function

```
Dim rec = (From a In dc.vHRIS_StaffDBs Where a.Lefe = False _
           And (x >= x.DisplayName.Matches(sname)) Select a.SID, _
           a.DisplayName Order By DisplayName).ToList
```

Comment: First, when posting code snippets, please take a little bit of time to format it - at least remove the huge amount of whitespace you had.  Second, what is the error you get in the LINQ statement?

Answer (score 0):

Make things a bit simpler... move your edit form into a user control with an entry like this:

```
<EditFormSettings EditFormType="WebUserControl" UserControlName="adminLookup.ascx">
```

In `adminLookup.ascx` add a [RadSearchBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/searchbox.aspx) that is bound to the list of users you want to be able to lookup.  You should then be able to debug and work through any issues with your lookup query easily in the isolated user control.

A demo of this functionality can be found here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/linqdatasource/defaultcs.aspx